# How to fix "too many values to unpack (expected 3)", when input more then 4 coordinate

Tags: python-3.x

The problem is everytime I input more then 4 coordinate, the computer shows too many values to unpack (expected 3)
the code:

```
import ast
def coordinate(getdata):
    l = ast.literal_eval(f"[{getdata}]")
    lx = [x for x,y,z in l]
    ly = [y for x,y,z in l]
    lz = [z for x,y,z in l]


    x = lx
    xv = [] 
    for f in range(len(x)-1):
        bx = x[f+1] - x[f]  
        xv.append(bx)   
    print(xv)

    y = ly
    yv = [] 
    for g in range(len(y)-1):
        by = y[g+1] - y[g]  
        yv.append(by)   
    print(yv)

    z = lz
    zv = [] 
    for h in range(len(z)-1):
        bz = z[h+1] - z[h]  
        zv.append(bz)   
    print(zv)
    
    co = []
    for x,y,z in zip(xv, yv, zv) :
        m = x,y,z
        co.append(m)
    print(co)
    col = ast.literal_eval(f"[{co}]")
    for zipx, zipy, zipz in col:
        for outx, outy, outz in zipx, zipy, zipz:
            print('x=', outx, 'turn:', (int(outx) * 2) / 100)
            print('y=', outy, 'turn:', (int(outy) * 2) / 100)
            print('z=', outz, 'turn:', (int(outz) * 2) / 100)
            print("------------------------------------------")
    
while True:
    getdata = input("coordinate in (x, y, z):")
    coordinate(getdata)
```

when I input (50,100,150), (51,102,149), (52,104,148), (53,106,147)
it would output like:

```
coordinate in (x, y, z):(50,100,150), (51,102,149), (52,104,148), (53,106,147)
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[-1, -1, -1]
[(1, 2, -1), (1, 2, -1), (1, 2, -1)]
x= 1 turn: 0.02
y= 2 turn: 0.04
z= -1 turn: -0.02
------------------------------------------
x= 1 turn: 0.02
y= 2 turn: 0.04
z= -1 turn: -0.02
------------------------------------------
x= 1 turn: 0.02
y= 2 turn: 0.04
z= -1 turn: -0.02
------------------------------------------
```

if input more then 4 coordinate, like (50,100,150), (51,102,149), (52,104,148), (53,106,147), (54,108,150)
it popup:

```
coordinate in (x, y, z):(50,100,150), (51,102,149), (52,104,148), (53,106,147), (54,108,150)
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[-1, -1, -1, 3]
[(1, 2, -1), (1, 2, -1), (1, 2, -1), (1, 2, 3)]

line 36, in coordinate
    for zipx, zipy, zipz in col:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

which means line 1 to line 28 with no problem, the problem come from somewhere from line 30 to line 41.
the code:

```
    co = []
    for x,y,z in zip(xv, yv, zv) :
        m = x,y,z
        co.append(m)
    print(co)
    col = ast.literal_eval(f"[{co}]")
    for zipx, zipy, zipz in col:
        for outx, outy, outz in zipx, zipy, zipz:
            print('x=', outx, 'turn:', (int(outx) * 2) / 100)
            print('y=', outy, 'turn:', (int(outy) * 2) / 100)
            print('z=', outz, 'turn:', (int(outz) * 2) / 100)
            print("------------------------------------------")
```

I tried change line 35 from `col = ast.literal_eval(f"[{co}]")` to `col = eval(co)`, it popup`eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`.
And use `col = eval(f"[{co}]")`, it pupup `too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

I will input whole bunch of coordinate in future, maybe 50, 100, 200, 1000 coordinate to help my job.

By the way i don't want to use eval() function, someone who answer my previous question, said try to not use eval() function, and he gave me a [website article](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Can you in detail explain what is the code designed to do and why do you expect the code to work when provided with more than 4 coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have provided is designed to take exactly four coordinates in order to work properly. So what seems to be wrong is your expectation that it should work for any number of coordinates, not only for a package of four.

By the way you can change one line with `eval` in your code as follows:

```
    #col = ast.literal_eval(f"[{co}]")
    col = [co]
```

And sure also get rid of the another statement with `eval` parsing the input string yourself in your code.

The code seem to be ready to take packages of four coordinates, but to provide this feature you need to re-design how it works and provide the input as a list of lists with four coordinate points in each list.